# Jscript open.window

Tags: javascript

```
function OpenPopup()
{
    window.open('myUpload.aspx', '', 'width=200,height=100');
}
```

I am getting Microsoft JScript runtime error: `Permission denied`, when I run the  above 
code.
I am using IE9 and VisualStudio 2010.

Comment: Missing quote in front of URL?

Comment: What is the code in myUpload.aspx?

Comment: Unused variable `formname`

Comment: how do you call the function? browsers usually block popups when their opening doesn't follow a user-action, e.g. a click-event

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
function OpenPopup(formname)
{
    window.open('http://localhost/myUpload.aspx', '', 'width=200,height=100');
}
```

Change the first parameter from `window.open` to your url

Answer (score 0):

Url parameter in your code should be fully qualified URL of your website/application.

Like this :

```
function OpenPopup()
{
    window.open('http://yourwebsite.com/myUpload.aspx', '', 'width=200,height=100');
}
```

You can change "http://yourwebsite.com/" to your localhost running instance url alongwith port number if you are debugging on you local machine.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have enabled popup blocker.